# Use Re.search to extract wanted text

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

My Script currently prints

```
<span class="price">€179.95</span>
```

I am trying to use re.search to extract just the price in €, so in this example I want to print "179", but unfortunately I am struggling with the use of re.search and advice or links to tutorials would be helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the following regex:

```
€(\d+)
```

Here's a regex 101 to play with it on:

https://regex101.com/r/8WYzaK/2

Additionally, you should be using `findall` for this:

```
import re
span = '<span class="price">€179.95</span>'
print(re.findall('€(\d+)',span))
```

If encoding doesn't work:

```
import re
span = '<span class="price">€179.95</span>'
print(re.findall('\u20AC(\d+)',span))
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to regex!

Comment: But for some reason when I try to implement this in python I get the following message "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file"

Comment: @Larsson Did you say yes to encoding it properly in Python?

Comment: @Larsson  Alternatively, you could use, `>.(\d+)`.

Comment: @nfnneil I'm not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: @Larsson For the regex you could use `>.(\d+)` if you can't correctly encode the euro character

Comment: @nfnneil I seem to be getting "TypeError: expected string or buffer" Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: @Larsson No problem, ummm... I'm running the code right now and it's working just fine.

Comment: How do I encode the euro character mate? This is what the issue seems to be @nfnneil I am getting "TypeError: expected string or buffer" as an error message?

Comment: @nfnneil Ah, now it is returning no values can I just send you my whole code please sorry about this

Comment: @Larsson Sure.  s

Comment: @nfnneil sweet! Send me a discord invite you one has expired pal

Comment: @nfnneil says expired can you give me your discord tag